# The print formatted known as printf in my program sadly won't run

Tags: c, printf

I'm really depressed because I tried to create a program using this code:

```
printf("hello world");
```

But it doesn't display Hello World in the log, what is wrong?

Comment: in "the log"? is your `stdout` redirected to "the log"? What platform are you on?

Comment: do you include the "stdio.h" ?

Comment: Is that the only line of code in your file ?

Comment: @Mike I am on the 3rd platform

Comment: @DamianNils What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Arnaldog Yes I did it

Comment: @DamianNils on the 3rd platform?

Comment: `the 3rd platform` You ask a lot of iOS questions... are you talking about a 3rd generation iphone?

Comment: In order to answer this question we need the following: What hardware are you targeting? What is the full code you're trying to compile? What compiler are you using? What command are you using to compile that code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A minimal hello world program in C looks like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

You first have to include `stdio.h` which gives you access to the `printf` function. Then you have to define a `main` function which is the entry point of the program. The code inside the main method will run, printing "Hello World" to the console and then the program exits with code 0, meaning that it ran successfully.

As you did not mention which compiler you use, or which compilation error you get, I can't do anything else for you.

Comment: @Armin void is not necessary.

Comment: @Armin: `foo(void)` means that function accepts no arguments. `foo()` means that function accepts any arguments. In fact, `main()` accepts `argc` and `argv`, so it is not `main(void)`.

Comment: Thanks I tried it and got this error : Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token "Invalid Character", interface 
  expected
 - Syntax error on token ">", { expected after this token
 - Syntax error on token ".", , expected

Comment: @VladLazarenko `int main(void)` is **just fine,** so is `int main()` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)` or in a freestanding environment, any other implementation-defined signature.

Comment: @H2CO3: I know, just uncovering a big idea behind `foo(void)` :)

Comment: thank you it worked. my program printed "hello world" but yours prints "Hello World" as i wanted to, thank you very much

Comment: 65 rep for a hello world program. that's a pretty sweet deal. ;)

Comment: @Mike: Yes it is! Pretty easy stuff :D

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your I/O is buffered. You might try flushing all open output streams by:

```
fflush(NULL);
```